# Form Validation with additional JQuery & Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a popup modal with inputs and a save button. I already have it to where each required field needs input before the Save button is enabled. What I would like to add is a class to the wrapping div to visually show which fields are required. So the form-group div would have a class of "has-error" until the input within gets text. I hope that makes sense.

See the **[JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/internetjason/quuq4h9k/)** or the Stack Snippet below. Stage & Description are required. But what other JQuery can I add without having to call it by ID? I want to call by class or "for each" because I want to adapt this code easily to other pages without changing each time.

An example... If Stage is blank, the form-group div that is wrapping it would have a class of has-error that would then go away once Stage has something in it.

```js
$('.required-input').keyup(function () {
    inspectrequired();
});

function inspectrequired() {
    var count = 0;
    $('.required-input').each(function (i) {
        if ($(this).val() === '') {
            count++;
        }
        if (count == 0) {
            $('.btn-success').prop('disabled', false);
        } else {
            $('.btn-success').prop('disabled', true);
        }
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://crm.champ.net/css/bootstrap.css">
<div class="row" id="popupmodal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="Stages" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">x</button>
                 <h4 class="modal-title" id="EditComanyModal">Add/Edit Stages</h4>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Stage</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control required-input" name="fstage" id="fstage">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Description</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control required-input" name="fdescription" id="fdescription">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger pull-left" id="cnamedel" name="cnamedel" onclick="fndelete();" data-dismiss="modal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span> Delete</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Cancel</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="cnamesave" name="cnamesave" onclick="fnsave();" disabled><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk"></span> Save</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I may be going at this the wrong way given that there are other validators out there, but this is in a popup modal so some of those other methods interfere.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [jQuery.validate](http://jqueryvalidation.org/) to do this. You now only get validation, but you can also add classes to inputs that have errors...

Comment: I ended up finding http://bootstrapvalidator.com/ which is very similar to what you listed above but uses a lot of the built-in BS classes. It also has a built-in workaround for the popup modal.